Laravel CreateNewUser script not committing certain fields fields to the database
I've logged throughout my web application and determined by form being submitted passes validation here:
 Validator::make($input, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'alpha', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'birthday' => ['required', 'date'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'alpha_dash', 'min:3', 'max:20', 'unique:users'],
            'country' => ['required', Rule::in(Country::pluck('name')->all())],
            'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'postal_code' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10', 'regex:/^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$|^[A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d$/i'],
            'timezone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50', Rule::in($timezoneNames)],
            'phone_number' => ['required', 'string', 'regex:/^\+?[1-9]\d{1,14}$/', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'password_confirmation' => ['required_with:password', 'same:password'],
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['accepted', 'required'] : '',
            // Optional fields
            'preferred_cuisine' => ['nullable', 'array'],
            'preferred_cuisine.*' => ['string', Rule::in($cuisineOptions)],
            'dietary_restrictions' => ['nullable', 'array'],
            'dietary_restrictions.*' => ['string', Rule::in($dietaryRestrictionsOptions)],
            'food_allergies' => ['nullable', 'array'],
            'food_allergies.*' => ['string', Rule::in($foodAllergiesOptions)],
            'cooking_skill_level' => ['nullable', 'string', Rule::in($cookingSkillLevels)],
            'cooking_frequency' => ['nullable', 'string', Rule::in($cookingFrequencies)],
            'newsletter_subscription' => ['boolean'],
        ])->validate();


But when it comes time to create the user after validation, all the fields from the // Optional Fields comment and below fail to show up in the database when I review it in dbeaver.
Here is how I'm trying to create the user:
return User::create([
            'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $input['last_name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'birthday' => $input['birthday'],
            'username' => $input['username'],
            'country' => $input['country'],
            'address' => $input['address'],
            'postal_code' => $input['postal_code'],
            'timezone' => $input['timezone'],
            'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            // Optional fields
            'preferred_cuisine' => $input['preferred_cuisine'] ?? null,
            'dietary_restrictions' => $input['dietary_restrictions'] ?? null,
            'food_allergies' => $input['food_allergies'] ?? null,
            'cooking_skill_level' => $input['cooking_skill_level'] ?? null,
            'cooking_frequency' => $input['cooking_frequency'] ?? null,
            'newsletter_subscription' => $input['newsletter_subscription'] ?? false,
        ]);

And for reference, here is my table migration script:
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name', 255);
            $table->string('last_name', 255);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->date('birthday');
            $table->string('username', 20)->unique();
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('address', 255);
            $table->string('postal_code', 10);
            $table->string('timezone', 50);
            $table->string('phone_number', 20)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
            // Optional fields
            $table->json('preferred_cuisine')->nullable();
            $table->json('dietary_restrictions')->nullable();
            $table->json('food_allergies')->nullable();
            $table->string('cooking_skill_level', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('cooking_frequency', 50)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('newsletter_subscription')->default(false);
        });

I'm pretty puzzled, everything I dd() or Log seems correct before being created. Here is an example:
[2024-06-25 03:54:53] local.DEBUG: Validated input data:  {"first_name":"Forrest","last_name":"Avery","email":"fugyzijusu@mailinator.com","birthday":"1997-04-08","username":"zisarafe","country":"United States","address":"Officia culpa volupt","postal_code":"68900","timezone":"America/Puerto_Rico","phone_number":"13526011041","password":"Pa$$w0rd!","password_confirmation":"Pa$$w0rd!","terms":true,"preferred_cuisine":["Chinese","French","Mexican"],"dietary_restrictions":["Vegan","Lactose-Free","Keto"],"food_allergies":["Tree Nuts","Eggs","Soy"],"cooking_skill_level":"Advanced","cooking_frequency":"Rarely","newsletter_subscription":true} 


Is your $fillable within the model contains  your Optional fields? It looks like they are missing from it.

@DhruvPandya That seemed to work for me I only had the additional fields in my $casts array and not in fillable.

@Anthony show the user model
